# Get day most closely following today from list of days in PHP string

Tags: php

I need to look at the contents of a string and determine what the day most closely following today would be.

For example. lets say I have a string called `$available_day_list` with the value "monday, thursday, friday, saturday,."

According to the list above, If today was tuesday, I would like to display "thursday."
If today was saturday, I would like to display "tuesday."

I am getting the value of today with:

```
$current_day = date("l");
$current_day = strtolower($current_day);
```

Anyone know how I might be able to do this without an array? Thanks all!!

Comment: What is your problem with arrays?

Comment: I would have no problem with an array, but the output isn't in an array right now, I am working with this string.

Comment: Something like this `echo date("l", strtotime("+ 2 days"));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$days = explode(',',$available_day_list);

$closestDay = '';
$minTime = 620000;// more than a week

foreach($days as $day){
    $diff = strtotime('next '.$day) - time();
    if($diff < $minTime){
        $closestDay = $day;
        $minTime = $diff;
    }
}

echo $closestDay;
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the value for $closestDay is blank. Any ideas why?

Comment: Make sure the days are spelled correctly and that there are no spaces between the day names and the commas in your string. If there are spaces use trim() to remove it at the beginning of the loop. I've tested the code works on my machine.

Comment: YOU NAILED IT!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

(i know, should've been written as a comment, but can't yet) Yotam's code turns the string into an array. And it works great, I'm not sure why you don't want to use arrays.

If you really don't though, you'll basically have to determine the current day, and then search through the string for the next day, and if not the next, and so on, until you find one.